# Flutter and Storing data

Tags: flutter, storing-data

I am kinda new in Flutter ,I am trying to store a list of some plain text like an array that user can access it later.How can I store it, Can I use local storage or do I need to store it in a database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in your use case you want to store locally so that you can fetch later right? Flutter has many libraries for your use case like [sqflite](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/sqflite) and you can check this medium post [link](https://medium.com/flutter-community/using-sqlite-in-flutter-187c1a82e8b) on how to implement the library.

Comment: Thank you #Dylan Chavez I will look sqflite later, It seems handy for me